# How to select the "Select with computer" button on Instagram and upload images using send_keys() method using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Trying to make a script/bot that interacts with Instagram (on chrome opened in debugger mode) after manual login and posts images.

I have managed to click the [+] button using selenium however I cannot deal with the "Select From Computer" button and use the `send_keys()` method to send images directly.

[The [+] sign button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHRst.png)

[Select From Computer button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ9dH.png)

code so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:1124")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options = opt)

uploadbutton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_acub")
uploadbutton.click()

time.sleep(1)

uploadfile = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "_acan _acap _acas")
uploadfile.send_keys("C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\ok.png")
```

the error occurred:

```
c:\Users\arjun\Desktop\Python\InstaBot.py:12: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options = opt)
c:\Users\arjun\Desktop\Python\InstaBot.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options = opt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\arjun\Desktop\Python\InstaBot.py", line 19, in <module>
    uploadfile = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "_acan _acap _acas")
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"_acan _acap _acas"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x003B6463+2188387]
        Ordinal0 [0x0034E461+1762401]
        Ordinal0 [0x00263D78+802168]
        Ordinal0 [0x00291880+989312]
        Ordinal0 [0x00291B1B+989979]
        Ordinal0 [0x002BE912+1173778]
        Ordinal0 [0x002AC824+1099812]
        Ordinal0 [0x002BCC22+1166370]
        Ordinal0 [0x002AC5F6+1099254]
        Ordinal0 [0x00286BE0+945120]
        Ordinal0 [0x00287AD6+948950]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006571F2+2712546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0064886D+2652765]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0044002A+520730]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0043EE06+516086]
        Ordinal0 [0x0035468B+1787531]
        Ordinal0 [0x00358E88+1805960]
        Ordinal0 [0x00358F75+1806197]
        Ordinal0 [0x00361DF1+1842673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75216739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77498FEF+1215]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77498FBD+1165]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `uploadfile = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Select from  computer")`

Comment: @dosas yup I did, but unfortunately, it says the same that it is unable to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/) to post on Instagram, which would be more efficient and easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).